# Mongoose - Find with and array

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have an array of objects : userNames , that contains

`[
  {
    name:"alice"
  },
  {
    name:"jhon"
  }
]`

and I have collection Users , I want to find users that theirs names are in userNames array without forEach ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mongo [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator to search by array values. Example:

```
const users = userNames.map(user => user.name);

User.find({ name: { $in: users } }).then(users =>
  console.log("There you are: ", users)
);
```